# passing variable to partial to controller via a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass a variable to a partial, then from the partial through a form to the controller, am I doing that correctly? The variable is called item_id.

#### The partial form entry + variable:

```
<%= form_tag contribute_stripe_path, method: :post do %>
...
<%= hidden_field_tag item_id %>
...
```

#### The controller

```
@item_id = params[:item_id]
item = Count.find(@item_id)
... 
item.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
```

#### Routes

```
post '/contribute', to: 'counts#stripe', as: 'contribute_stripe'
```

Comment: Well, this seems correct. Don't forget about the condition to check whether an `item` exists. Also I believe this should be: `hidden_field_tag 'item_id', item_id`

Comment: Are you facing any issues(post the error part), also post the html code from where the partial is being called. The current flow looks fine.

Comment: The item_id was not passing, @bodrovis and Fer's answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the error usually helps.

What I see is the way you are defining the field is wrong.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, item_id %>
```

The first param sets the field name, and the second one, its value (if the `item_id` variable is defined... if not you will get an error)